# subgraphing in a foreach loop in spark and graphx problems

Tags: scala, foreach, network-programming, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Hoping somebody can help.

I'm trying to write a program which needs to carry out a function on each edge ID connected to each node in a network on graphx.

To do this I want to iterate over each node and identify all edges connected to it, I then want to iterate over each edge with a function. My problem seems to arise when doing any kind of subgraphing or filtering within a foreach loop.

So for example the code below should output the id of each edge connected to a node

```
graph.vertices.foreach {
  network => 
    val KeyVert = network._1
val EGraph = graph.subgraph(e => e.dstId == KeyVert)
println(KeyVert)
EGraph.edges.foreach(println)
}
```

However it will only work if you add the collect function to collect the graph data from the rdd e.g.

```
graph.vertices.collect.foreach {
  network => 
    val KeyVert = network._1
val EGraph = graph.subgraph(e => e.dstId == KeyVert)
println(KeyVert)
EGraph.edges.foreach(println)
}
```

The network is too large to be collecting edge data so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

em...the problem is you did not  understand the driver and the worker...when you call collect function, all data are collected to the driver, and then foreach function looks work well. In fact, `graph.vertices.foreach` did not report any error, right? because it works well really, just println the info at the worker's log. you know what I said? hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
graph.vertices.map {
  network => 
    val KeyVert = network._1
  val EGraph = graph.subgraph(e => e.dstId == KeyVert)
  println(KeyVert)
  EGraph.edges.map(println)
}
```

That may solve your problem.